# MailChimp PUT /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash} Interests Additive?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm implementing the MailChimp APIs in my order processing system. I'm looking to automatically update interests for my subscribers when they order products from two categories.

After logging their order in MailChimp, I'm calling the `PUT /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}` API to log the interest tied to the current order. E.g if the current order is an app, I'd put them in the "software" interest.

My concern is, let's say this user bought a book before, so they're already a subscriber with the "books" interest. If I send a PUT request to this with *only* the "software" interest set to true, does that remove the previous interest already saved with the subscriber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sending a PUT request that contains only a single interest will not affect any of the subscriber's other interests. Using your example, if a subscriber already has the 'books' interest set to *true*, then a new request that sets the 'software' interest to *true* will result in both interests being *true*.

The result of the PUT request will contain the interest IDs and their statuses in the response, something like this:

```
...
"interests": {
    "books_interest_id": true,
    "software_interest_id": true
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, I can tweak user interests as I find out more about them, without overriding other interests by accident.